# Being on two iPhone developer teams

Tags: iphone

When I am invited to join a team through the iPhone Developer Portal, should I create a new Development Certificate in my name specifically for that team, or should I simply use the Certificate that I already have? (For my own business)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you just do Debug builds I suppose it doesn't matter which provisioning profile you use. Release builds have to be made with the correct certificate, of course.

Comment: I'm not talking about the provisioning profile. I'm talking about the certificate. I currently have one developer identity in my keychain, my own. The question is whether I should create another one for each team that I join?

Comment: Same difference, isn't it? As long as you just do debugging, the device doesn't care (or know) what company you're working for.

Comment: YEah I guess as long as I am not making Ad Hoc profiles it should be fine. Specially with the new Xcode auto-profile-selection.

Comment: `Have to be *made* with`, not `mad with`. ;)